# Сравнить 2 датафрейма и показать изменения

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, сравнение

Подскажите, пожалуйста как при сравнение 2-х датафреймов в pandas вывести только произошедшие изменения по условиям.

df1:

```
Id   Name  Amount Contract_ID  Date
195   ART   200     23rt       2019-02-21
264   Pict  150     18f        2019-01-17
482   Tras  379     427df      2019-02-10
294   Fish  375     29fg       2019-02-11
```

df2

```
Id   Name  Amount  Contract_ID  Date
195    ART   250      23rt       2019-03-26
190    Tree  100      312ft      2019-03-15
482    Tras  379      427df      2019-03-20
264    Pict  50       18f        2019-04-01
294    Fish  450      29fg       2019-04-20
294    Fish  100      26394rt    2019-03-20
```

Нужно получить следующий результат - создать датафрейм где будут только те row, где произошло увеличение суммы, либо новые row:

```
df_update:
195    ART   250      23rt       2019-03-26
190    Tree  100      312ft      2019-03-15
294    Fish  450      29fg       2019-04-20
294    Fish  100      26394rt    2019-03-20
```

Попытался это сделать следующим кодом, но не получил требуемого результата:

```
df_update = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', indicator=True).query("_merge == 'right_only'")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пошаговое решение:

делаем `"FULL OUTER JOIN"` по столбцам `['Id','Name','Contract_ID']` с индикацией. Столбцы второго DF, не участвующие в объединении, получат суфикс `_new`:

```
m = (d1.merge(d2, how='outer', on=['Id','Name','Contract_ID'], 
              suffixes=['', '_new'], indicator=True))
```

---

```
In [39]: m
Out[39]:
    Id  Name  Amount Contract_ID       Date  Amount_new   Date_new      _merge
0  195   ART   200.0        23rt 2019-02-21         250 2019-03-26        both
1  264  Pict   150.0         18f 2019-01-17          50 2019-04-01        both
2  482  Tras   379.0       427df 2019-02-10         379 2019-03-20        both
3  294  Fish   375.0        29fg 2019-02-11         450 2019-04-20        both
4  190  Tree     NaN       312ft        NaT         100 2019-03-15  right_only
5  294  Fish     NaN     26394rt        NaT         100 2019-03-20  right_only
```

---

заполним отсутствующие значения в столбцах `['Amount', 'Date']` из соответствующих строк в `DF2` (этот шаг можно пропустить):

```
m[['Amount', 'Date']] = (m[['Amount', 'Date']]
                         .apply(lambda c: c.combine_first(m[f'{c.name}_new'])))
```

---

```
In [41]: m
Out[41]:
    Id  Name  Amount Contract_ID       Date  Amount_new   Date_new      _merge
0  195   ART   200.0        23rt 2019-02-21         250 2019-03-26        both
1  264  Pict   150.0         18f 2019-01-17          50 2019-04-01        both
2  482  Tras   379.0       427df 2019-02-10         379 2019-03-20        both
3  294  Fish   375.0        29fg 2019-02-11         450 2019-04-20        both
4  190  Tree   100.0       312ft 2019-03-15         100 2019-03-15  right_only
5  294  Fish   100.0     26394rt 2019-03-20         100 2019-03-20  right_only
```

---

выбираем только интересующие нас строки:

```
m.query("Amount_new > Amount or _merge=='right_only'")
```

---

```
In [42]: m.query("Amount_new > Amount or _merge=='right_only'")
Out[42]:
    Id  Name  Amount Contract_ID       Date  Amount_new   Date_new      _merge
0  195   ART   200.0        23rt 2019-02-21         250 2019-03-26        both
3  294  Fish   375.0        29fg 2019-02-11         450 2019-04-20        both
4  190  Tree   100.0       312ft 2019-03-15         100 2019-03-15  right_only
5  294  Fish   100.0     26394rt 2019-03-20         100 2019-03-20  right_only
```

Comment: Спасибо большое